# Intentionally stop a process from responding

Tags: centos, bind, process, strace

Is there any way to intentionally prevent a process from responding - ie. not close or kill it, but stop it dead in it's track, so it immediately stops processing anything?

I've often found myself wanting to force a process into a non-responsive state to test some sort of handler for when this really happens for whatever reason.

Currently I'm working on centos 5.5, and specifically want to prevent `named` from responding - it happens occasionally under "normal conditions" (ie. cause unknown), and I need to react to that... but testing is rather difficult when I need to wait (for weeks) for it to happen randomly.

I suppose a good indicator that the process is dead would be that `strace -p 1234` is silent.

A generic solution is preferred, but if you have any ideas that would cover just this specific case, please do post an answer anyway.

Comment: Is `kill -19` (aka `kill -stop`) out of the question?

Comment: I didn't do my homework properly before posting the question, cause `strace` on the main process is actually totally silent even when everything is running as it should :p The children are doing stuff though, and `kill -19` on one of the children actually produces the exact results I was hoping for...

Comment: Glad to hear it.  You want me to write that up as an answer, so you can accept it, or just delete the question?

Comment: I think the question is quite relevant, cause google turned up next to nothing (or rather turned up a heap of irrelevant info on how to kill non-responsive processes)... Go on and post an answer, but I may give it a few days before accepting it, just to see if anyone else has any interesting ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suspend a process by sending it SIGSTOP, and resume it by sending SIGCONT.

```
kill -STOP <pid>
```

and

```
kill -CONT <pid>
```

respectively.

Comment: These signals and many others are described in the [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page.